# Webpage search filter inputs not detected when apply button is pressed via Excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to write a VBA program which will find the person holding a specific position at a specific company via LinkedIn. I've already figured out how to open the LinkedIn search window, open all filters, and input the desired company name and position, but ***once I hit the "Apply" button to apply those filters, they simply aren't recognized as filters***. It clicks the button as if I never input anything into those filter boxes at all.

I've figured out that the problem is not my method of clicking the apply button, but instead the lack of input recognition. ***My input strings are only recognized as filters if their respective filter area/box is clicked on before or after the string is added.***

With all that being said, I know that the solution I'm looking for is a way to input the string *and then click into that same filter box before I click the apply filters button.*

Below is my code to input my specific filters into LinkedIn and click the apply button.

```
Sub Fill()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim AllFiltersButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim ApplyButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement2
Dim ApplyButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection2

Dim Company As String, Position As String

Company = Range("A2").Value
Position = ("""" + Range("B1").Value + """")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?facetGeoRegion=%5B%22us%3A70%22%5D&origin=FACETED_SEARCH"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each AllFiltersButton In HTMLButtons
    If AllFiltersButton.className = "search-filters-bar__all-filters button-tertiary-medium-muted flex-shrink-zero mr3" Then AllFiltersButton.Click
Next AllFiltersButton

Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("search-advanced-company")
HTMLInput.Value = Company

Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("search-advanced-title")
HTMLInput.Value = Position

Set ApplyButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each ApplyButton In ApplyButtons
    If ApplyButton.className = "search-advanced-facets__button--apply button-primary-large" Then ApplyButton.Click
Next ApplyButton
```

I have all the necessary references selected (Microsoft HTML Object Library, Microsoft Internet Controls, Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library etc.)
and this portion of the code seems to work flawlessly.

After spending hours trying to figure out a way to click in these search/filter boxes, I stumbled across a method which should work, but I can't seem to adapt the code for my specific circumstance.

```
Set evt = ie.Document.createEvent("keyboardevent")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
PW.all(0).dispatchEvent evt
```

My attempt to adapt this method to click into the company search box (but doesn't work) is as follows:

```
Dim vSelect As HTMLSelectElement
Dim eventClick As Object

Set vSelect = HTMLDoc.getElementById("search-advanced-company")
Set eventClick = HTMLDoc.createEvent("click")
eventClick.initEvent "change", True, False
vSelect.dispatchEvent eventClick
```

How should I adapt this code to click into a search/filter box?

If any one could help me out in any way, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm getting mixed information as to whether data scraping on LinkedIn is permitted or not. Just to clarify, **I will not** be using this code for data scraping to avoid any infringement issues.

Comment: Does the linkedin 'terms and conditions' allow web scraping?

Comment: @Jeeped  Good question. I'm no lawyer, but [it seems to be okay](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/08/linkedin-ruling-scraping) (but, who knows if this applies to specific users, for their specific case, getting whatever specific data).

Comment: **Prohibited Software and Extensions** ... *Develop, support or use software, devices, scripts, robots, or any other means or processes (including crawlers, browser plugins and add-ons, or any other technology) to scrape the Services or otherwise copy profiles and other data from the Services;* ... *Any member who uses tools for such purposes is in violation of the User Agreement. ...*

Comment: @Jeeped To avoid any litigation issues, I might just use vba to conduct the search and then I'll manually get their name after the search is conducted so no data scraping is involved. It'll still save me some time.

Comment: @Jeeped or maybe try to use LinkedIn's API. I spent some good time on this code though so I would still like to at least try to get over this hurdle, but obviously without committing any infringement.

Comment: @dav278 - I've done a lot of scraping, everything from stock info to grocery flyers; perhaps a little background would help generate some suggestions for you.  What is the end goal? Contact information? Do you know of a company & position for someone and you want to find a name & contact info?  Is this one specific person or a list of specific people, or unknowns across many companies?  Depending on this, I may have an alternative for you

Comment: @ashleedawg Essentially I'm given a list of companies, and I need to find the people that hold a certain position there. There's about 5 or 6 positions I'm interested in. Since I work at a recruiting and consulting firm, we have other resources to contact these people if we have the ability to.

Comment: @dav278 - Have you seen [**Hunter.io**](https://hunter.io/)?  Enter a company and/or title/department and get a list of email addresses.  I use it constantly for both work and personal reasons (eg., companies that try to avoid giving direct customer service but have "secret' email addresses, like eBay and Spotify.)

Comment: @ashleedawg I haven’t heard of it, but it sounds like a resource definitely worth looking into. I’ll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @dav278 You're welcome.  As for the code snippet you stumbled upon, it uses the [***deprecated* `Event.initEvent()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent), which would be *why* it doesn't work.

Comment: @dav278 -  As for a solution to your issue, perhaps VBA's `SendKeys` command would work for you. [**Here's one example**](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/) (see the section "SendKeys to Internet Explorer").  (Heads up, that site has annoying popups so I'm gonna block it; I'm sure there are others.)

Comment: @ashleedawg I read a couple things suggesting that the SendKeys method is a method you should avoid, which deterred me from using it, but it doesn't hurt to try. I'll try it in the morning. Thanks again for the all the help!

Comment: Correct, there's various reasons to avoid `SendKeys`. It's also identical to the deprecated `keyboardevent` that you intended to use. ;) I've learned over the years that there is good reason behind many of the "coding best practices" that at first don't seem to make any sense. (example: I fought other people's expectations of indentation and spacing, "why waste my time with that, it doesn't *do* anything!"... but eventually I realized the advantage of doing things in a standardized way.)  I am also a believer that, at the end of the day, the right way to do it is "the way that works!"

Comment: ...so hopefully someone else has an alternate suggestion, and be sure to do more research before using SendKeys, but if you can't find any other way to get the job done, do what you gotta do... also don't be surprised if something reacts not-as-expected.  Use lots of error handling and protect critical data related to the process.  If you prepare for the worst, you will never be disappointed. :)\

Comment: @ashleedawg I'm trying out all of your suggestions right now. Thanks so much for all the help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

After resorting to the often avoided and disrespected `SendKeys` function, I was finally able to make it work.

Below is the corrected code:

```
Sub Fill()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLInputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection2
Dim AllFiltersButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim ApplyButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim ApplyButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection3
Dim Company As String, Position As String

Company = Range("A2").Value
Position = ("""" + Range("B1").Value + """")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?facetGeoRegion=%5B%22us%3A70%22%5D&origin=FACETED_SEARCH"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each AllFiltersButton In HTMLButtons
    If AllFiltersButton.className = "search-filters-bar__all-filters button-tertiary-medium-muted flex-shrink-zero mr3" Then AllFiltersButton.Click
Next AllFiltersButton

Set HTMLInputs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
HTMLInputs(2).Value = Position
HTMLInputs(2).Focus
Application.SendKeys "{LEFT}", True

HTMLInputs(3).Value = Company
HTMLInputs(3).Focus
Application.SendKeys "{LEFT}", True

Set ApplyButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each ApplyButton In ApplyButtons
    If ApplyButton.className = "search-advanced-facets__button--apply button-primary-large" Then ApplyButton.Click
Next ApplyButton

End Sub
```

A big "Thank you!" to @ashleedawg for the suggestion leading to the solution!